# Keeping track of cards in a storage piles in C# with out a database

Tags: c#

I have a card game that I am developing and in the said game you can have up to 4 storage piles. the way it works is to end your turn you play a card to said storage pile:

```
namespace Shikana.Game.Logic.Players.StoragePiles
{
    public enum Piles
    {
        PileA = 1,
        PileB = 2,
        PileC = 3,
        PileD = 4
    }
}
```

My goal is, without the use of a database (including SQLite), to keep track of the order of cards in each storage pile for a player, throughout the whole game (start to finish). The player class or at least the parts you need to care about for this question is below:

```
namespace Shikana.Game.Logic.Players
{
    public class Player
    {
        public void playersHand(List<Card> cards)
        {
            this.Hand = cards;
        }

       /// ...

        public void storeCard(Card card, Piles pile)
        {
            Storage cardPile = new Storage(card, pile);

            List<Storage> storage = new List<Storage>();
            storage.Add(cardPile);
            this.StoragePiles = storage;
        }

        public List<Card> Hand { get; private set; }

        public List<Storage> StoragePiles { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Here we just store a card into a list, via the `storeCard()` method, which takes a Card obj and a Pile from the enum of `Piles`:

```
namespace Shikana.Game.Logic.Players.StoragePiles
{
    public class Storage
    {
        public Storage(Card card, Piles pile)
        {
            this.Card = card;
            this.Pile = pile;
        }

        public bool validatePile(Piles pile)
        {
            return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Piles), pile);
        }


        public Card Card { get; private set; }

        public Piles Pile { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

With all that said the end result of storing multiple cards will be:

```
<(Card, PileA), (Card, PileB), (Card, PileC), ...>
```

I need to re-write the `Storage` class to add to a list or create said the list of cards for a specific pile the player wants to store a card in when they end their turn. A player can ONLY have 4 storage piles and can ONLY store one card per turn.

The list must be ordered where the card placed in storage, at the end of said turn, is placed at the bottom. A player must play bottom-up from that list of cards for that said pile.

The question is:

**How do I re-write the storage class to store cards for a specific pile and be able to update said pile when the player chooses to end his turn by playing a card to the storage pile?**

*Everything I think of leads me back to create databases including player objects, play pile objects, and relationships to cards. But again I want NOTHING to do with a database and should be able to store this information in the player object somehow.*

Comment: You could serialize the collections

Comment: Just use an in-memory collection.  Use a database when you need to persist the data, which in this case you don't.

Comment: Well, since you have 4 stacks of cards, I would use 4 `Stacks` to store them.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I was thinking of this but I felt that was really messy, because then that leads, off topic, to play piles where there is 8 stacks. Back on topic, would enums even be needed here then, if I went the us x stacks route?

Comment: Wait, are there 4 stacks or 8 stacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Stack` collections to store each pile, you can simplify quite a bit of code.

First, redefine your enum values to serve as indices:

```
public enum Piles
{
  PileA, // initial value is zero
  PileB,
  PileC,
  PileD,
}
```

Then, define your storage class to use one instance only for each player:

```
public class Storage
{
  private List<Stack<Card>> _piles;

  public void Add(Card card, Piles pile)
  {
    int idx = (int)pile;
    _piles[idx].Push(card);
  }

  public Storage()
  {
    _piles = new List<Stack<Card>>();
    _piles.Add(new Stack<Card>());
    _piles.Add(new Stack<Card>());
    _piles.Add(new Stack<Card>());
    _piles.Add(new Stack<Card>());
  }
}
```

Each pile is a `Stack` instance that maintains the LIFO order of the cards as they are added and removed. Each pile is stored in a containing list so that it can be accessed by index.

```
public class Player
{
  public void playersHand(List<Card> cards)
  {
    this.Hand = cards;
  }

  /// ...

  public void storeCard(Card card, Piles pile)
  {
    this.StoragePiles.Add(card, pile);
  }

  public List<Card> Hand
  {
    get; private set;
  }

  public Storage StoragePiles
  {
    get; private set;
  }
}
```

This way, all you have to do is tell the storage instance which pile you want the card in, and it will push it onto the correct stack.

Note that this does NOT track the overall play order of ALL cards, only for each individual stack.

Comment: For each individual stack would be fine when tracking order of cards.